# Why is there so many expression terminators in OCaml?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I noticed that the OCaml syntax is unusually rich with different ways of expressing seemingly the same constructs. For example, there are multiple ways to terminate an expression in OCaml, e.g., `;;`, `;`, `in`, `,` and, sometimes, no terminator at all. There are also many different kinds of parentheses, that are apparently interchangeable, e.g., `()`, `{}`, and `[]`.

Why are there so many syntactical constructs in OCaml and is there a good summary that highlights the differences between those constructs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are zero expression terminators in OCaml. I don't think that this is too many :)

Let's go through the examples of what you think is a terminator.

- `;;` is not really a part of OCaml syntax. It is indeed a terminator, which is used in the interactive toplevel to send the code block for execution. For compatibility, this symbol is allowed in OCaml code, but in general, you shouldn't use it. Even in a toplevel, you are usually using some shortcut, e.g., `Shift-Enter` in Emacs, which will send the code for you.
- `;` is used as a separator in different collections literals, i.e., lists, arrays, etc. It is also used to chain two side effect expressions, e.g., `print_int 1; print_int 2` is an expression, that first computes `print_int 1` and ignores its result, and then computes `print_int 2` and also ignores its result.
- `in` is used in the middle of a `let <var> = <expr> in <body>` expression, which constructs an expression `<body`> where all occurences of `<var>` a substituted with `<expr>`, e.g.,

  ```
  let x = 2 in x * x
  ```

  is the same as `2 * 2`.
- different parenthesis are used to define different types of collections, e.g.,

  - `("42",42,'42')` - defines a tuple
  - `[1;2;3;4]` - a signly-linked monomorphic list
  - `[| 1;2;3;4 |]` - a fixed-size array
  - `{ name = "Joe"; age = 12}` - a record (which is a tuple with named fields)

Overall, OCaml is a very rich language with many features. One of the main features of the language is automatic type inference, where the type of an expression is inferred automatically (without any annotations from a programmer). Therefore, the code shall be self-describing, because unlike other languages where the typing context defines the semantics of a syntactic construct, in OCaml it is the other way around - the syntactic construct defines the semantics, and therefore the type. For example, in languages without automatic type inference, it is possible to use the same syntax for literals of different types (cf., initialization lists in C), since the definition context defines which particular type is actually used. Contrary, in OCaml the literal itself shall define the context that is necessary for recovering its type. As a nice side-effect, the OCaml syntax is so explicit that it is always possible and easy for someone who is reading it to manually infer the type and understand the semantics of the code, without looking anywhere else.

With all that said, it is extremely easy to learn OCaml syntax and OCaml in general, as it is well-defined with no dark corners or multiple interpretations. It is made such by design. There are lots of [books](https://ocaml.org/learn/books.html), that will help you in learning OCaml, as well as other [learning resources](https://ocamlverse.github.io/content/learning.html). And at the end of the day, you will start to think that this is the other languages that have weird syntax :)

Concerning their comparison on one place, there is such a place - it is called OCaml Manual, which describes formally and precisely the meaning of each symbol. The [Chapter 7](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/language.html) is a little bit terse and formal, so I would suggest to read it after the first 6. But it actually contains everything in EBNF-like notation, e.g., here is the [expression](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) grammar.

Finally, if you really can't live with OCaml syntax, there is [Reason](https://reasonml.github.io/), which is OCaml with a syntax that looks more conventional for someone with Javascript or C background.

Comment: Very well explained. I'll wait for some more time for any other answers before accepting.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a couple more links, to make it easier for you to find yourself in the OCaml world. OCaml is huge and is a little bit overwhelming when you just start learning it. Maybe you're starting too fast, my suggestion is to find some course or book, which will give you a gentle introduction into the language.

Comment: For sake of completeness, you can briefly mention about 'in' keyword also.